# how to make instances of particle system spin around only one axis?

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to make a particle system with maple seeds falling on the ground. The seeds should be spinning only around the z-axis and react to force fields like wind or turbulence. Is it possible to lock the rotation of the particles for the x and the y axis? When applying a force field, they rotate in every direction.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be it ... *Particles System Properties > Rotation*

[image]
Origin at rotation axis

Enable **Dynamic** and set *Angular Velocity* to *Global Z*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ah ... now I noticed - shockwave :) No problem :)