# How I can create fire particles

Tags: particles

How I can create fire particles [like this site](https://ironvelvet.studio/works) in blender?

There is a tutorial or an example of this effect ?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Particle systems are a thing, and emission shaders are a thing. The trick I think will be getting the particles to move about in an erratic fashion, though a turbulence field just might do it. After that, I think lighting just needs to move about and change intensity on a noise function.

Comment: Maybe create 2 particle systems, one for the slow ash pieces and one for the fast spark particles. Here is a simple example for the setup (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuaBm.jpg) and related question of how to give particles a rotation around their own axis (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265806/107598).